# Select total members and amount paid

Tags: mysql, sql

I need help generating SQL for MySQL database.

I have three tables:

- Organisations
- Members
- Payments

**Organisations table:**

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|    id      |  name   |website |
+------------+---------+--------+
| 1          | AAA     | a.com  |
|-------------------------------+
| 2          | BBB     | b.com  |
+------------+---------+--------+
```

**Members table:**

```
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------+
|    id      |  organisation_id  |name    | Payment_confirm | join_date |
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------+
| 1          | 1                 | james  | 1               | 2013-8-02 |
|-----------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 2          | 1                 | Jimmy  | 0               | 2013-6-25 |
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------+
| 3          | 2                 | Manny  | 1               | 2013-07-02|
|-----------------------------------------+-----------------+-----------+
| 4          | 1                 | Kim    | 1               | 2013-09-02|
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+-----------+
```

**Payments table:**

```
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
|    id      |  member_id        |amount  | transaction_id  | transferred_at |
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 1          | 1                 | 100    | T1001           | 2013-8-03      |
|-----------------------------------------+-----------------+--------------- +
| 2          | 2                 | 0      | null            | Null           |
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
| 3          | 3                 | 200    | T1002           | Null           |
|-----------------------------------------+-----------------+----------------+
| 4          | 4                 | 50     | T1005           | 2013-09-05     |
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+----------------+
```

How can I select the following?

Expecting the following output:

```
+------------+-------------------+--------+-----------------+---------------+--------------+ 
|  Org name  |  Revenue          |untransferred amount      | Total members | last 30 days |
+------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| AAA        | 150               | 0                        | 3             |  2           |
|-----------------------------------------------------------+---------------+--------------+
| BBB        | 200               | 200                      | 1             |  0           |   
+------------+-------------------+--------------------------+---------------+--------------+


Org name              = organisation name
Revenue               = Total amount received
untransferred amount  = transferred_at is null (payments table)
Total members         = total members joined till today
last 30 days          = total members joined last 30 days
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to join your tables, group the results and select the desired logic:

```
SELECT   org.name,
         SUM(pmt.amount) AS revenue,
         SUM(IF(pmt.transferred_at IS NULL, pmt.amount, 0)) AS untransferred
FROM     Organisations org
    JOIN Members       mem ON mem.organisation_id = org.id
    JOIN Payments      pmt ON pmt.member_id       = mem.id
GROUP BY org.id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/42e988/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.name, 
sum(amount) as Revenue,
sum(if(transferred_at is null, amount, 0)) as untransfered_ammt,
sum(if(join_date>=curdate() - interval 30 day, 1, 0)) as last_30_d


from organisations o
inner join members m on o.id=m.organisation_id
inner join payments p on p.member_id=m.member_id
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. can i run this query with php?

Comment: Thank you. sum(if(join_date>=curdate() - interval 30 day, 1, 0) as last_30_d this line giving error? sorry i am new in SQL. I might missing something.

Comment: forgot a paranthesis, trz now

Comment: error:Unknown column 'o.organisation_id' in 'on clause': select o.name, sum(amount) as Revenue, sum(if(transferred_at is null, amount, 0)) as untransfered_ammt, sum(if(join_date>=curdate() - interval 30 day, 1, 0)) as last_30_d from organisations o inner join members m on o.organisation_id=m.organisation_id inner join payments p on p.member_id=m.member_id group by 1 pmt.amount, 0)) AS untransferred sum(if(join_date>=curdate() - interval 30 day, 1, 0)) as last_30_d FROM Organisations org JOIN Members mem ON mem.organisation_id = org.id JOIN Payments pmt ON pmt.member_id = mem.id GROUP BY org.id

Comment: your query is missing a comma
 "AS untransferred >COMMA< sum(if(join_date>=curdate()"

Comment: also corrected column name from orga table. Any other errors? :)